# How to convert a JSON into a Hashmap in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, string, parsing, hashmap

I am attempting to convert a HTTP request body in JSON format into a hashmap. Below is how my request looks:

```
{
  "car": [{
      "ford": "focus",
      "audi": "a6"
  }],
  "food": [{
      "soup": "leek"
  }]
}
```

And below is the code I have tried so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/items', async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let jsonString = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  let jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  let jsonMap = new Map(Object.entries(jsonObject));
  var mainArray = {};
  var carKey = 'car';
  mainArray[carKey] = [];
  for (var entry of jsonMap.entries()) {
    let key = entry[0], value = entry[1];
    let innerJson = JSON.stringify(value);
    let innerJsonObj = JSON.parse(innerJson);
    for(var innerKey in innerJsonObj) {
      let tempStr = JSON.stringify(innerJsonObj[innerKey]);
      let tempVal = JSON.parse(tempStr);
      let attr = '';
      let param = '';
      for(var k in tempVal) {
        attr = k;
        param = tempVal[k];
        logger.info(k + "=" + tempVal[k]);
      }
      let result = someMethod(param);
      var carData = {
        attr : JSON.stringify(result);
      }
      mainArray[carKey].push(carData);
    }
  }
});
```

I want to display the results in the same way as received in the request, but with the use of the binary result of someMethod(). Below is what im trying to create as a response.

```
{
    "car": [
        {
            "ford": "binarydata",
            "audi": "binarydata"
        }
    ],
    "food": [
        {
            "soup": "binarydata"           
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This could be related to asynchronous behaviour. The request is asynchronous and maybe you are trying to access the results before the response has arrived.

Comment: I am able to view it when i stringify() the req.body, so the next lines should be able to process that into a map, but it doesnt appear to. Does async behaviour affect those lines?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it would only affect it if those lines were not part of the same function execution context (one part in a callback another not). If this is not your case, then please make it reproducible in a runnable snippet (use toolbar), feeding it with the JavaScript object you get as response.

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work in the toolbar either. It gives a ScriptError on line 0. I have updated the post with the imports used. I am also using node 14 instead of 17.

Comment: Please verify that `jsonMap.size` is equal to `Object.keys(jsonObject).length`. Output both of them at the same time.

Comment: Both statements result in the value '2', which indicates it is storing the request data somewhat.

Comment: So then the question is: what is ... your question now?

Comment: I see it can process the two keys but not the values, as I was thinking they were a Map, but are actually Array format. I can now see the data but want to iterate through the array rather than have to reference directly the keys inside.

Comment: I don't follow... Can you update your question to reflect the new insights?

Comment: In the updated code there are now many more variables. Which variable or property has the unexpected value, and at which line of the code? NB: `someMethod` is suspicious. If it is asynchronous, then `result` will be a promise at best, but certainly not the value that will be asynchronously determined. This is what I hinted at in my first comment.

Comment: I have updated it with further developed code. It is working in that I can recieve the results of the map, but the response object im trying to achieve isnt quite correct. How can i get the values of the keys set in the format needed?

Comment: Why do you need a `Map` for this or all these other operations you do? I'm confused. If I understand correctly, all you want is to replace the inner values by passing through a method... right? `for (const object of Object.values(req.body).flat()) for (const key of Object.keys(object)) object[key] = someMethod(object[key]); return req.body`...right?

Comment: Actually I am trying to parse the req.body to read the inner values of each car and soup, encode them, then return them in a response in the same json format as the request. Typically I would use res.end() and pass in the response json

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to achieve this using the code below. This allows me to specify the key and value in the JSON I add to the array via the push() command. Thank you for the guidance.

```
      var carData = {};
      carData[attr] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`${result}`)); 
      mainArray[carKey].push(carData);
```

Comment: What is the sense of stringifying a string?